# Why is this jQuery show & hide script not working as expected?

Tags: jquery, html, hide, accordion, show

I'm rather new to coding, and I'm kind of stuck on a **accordion-style device** I'm trying to make.

The idea is to have 4 div-elements and below them another div. When clicking one of the 4 divs, a correlating text is to be displayed in the box; clicking another, the text of the first div disappears and changes to the other. clicking the same, the box just disappears.

My game plan: assign the same class to all elements which are supposed to be hidden and hide them on site launch; when a div is clicked, display only the element which has a corresponding ID.

Currently, I'm stuck at getting it to work with even just one div, and I don't know why. I'd be grateful if you could tell me where the problem lies.

My code thus far (only 2 divs now, to make this less cluttered):

HTML:

```
<div class="expander" id="first-p">Click this text to see the one below.</div>
<div class="expander" id="second-p">Another clickable div.</div>
<div class="concealed" id="concealed-first-p">This is the hidden text.</div>
<div class="concealed" id="concealed-second-p">This is another hidden text.</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".concealed").hide();             //hide all elements with class .concealed after site launch

    $(".expander").click(function(){             //A div which triggers the displaying of the hidden stuff is clicked


/* If the hidden div is already displayed, hide it instead and call it a day */

            if (clickedElement == $(this).attr("id")) {
                alert ("hide div again");
                $("#expandingElement").hide(); 
            }

/* Show the hidden div */

else {
            $("#expandingElement").hide();             // hide any div that might already be displayed
            var clickedElement = $(this).attr("id");            // get the ID of the clicked element so we know which correlating one to display afterwards
            var expandingElement = "concealed-" + clickedElement;            // construct the ID of the element to display
            alert("Name of expandingElement ID is " + expandingElement);             // this is just an alert so I know the variable was constructed correctly
            $("#expandingElement").show();             // show the div
            }
        });
    });
```

So far, the code works up until the point where the alert shows the correct variable name, but the div doesn't show up afterwards. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, I imagine there's easier ways to do this, and I'll gladly take any help on this matter. But most of all, I'd like learn why the code is not working as intended.

Comment: Which part of your `html` has `id` `expandElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have messed up the selectors:

None of your divs has the ID "expandingElement" but you call

```
$("#expandingElement").hide()
```

This tries to apply the hide() to an element with the ID expandingElement. But you want to use variable named expandingElement. So what you need to do is concat these two properly:

```
$("#"+expandingElement).hide()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and newbie-friendly explanation!

Comment: I already upvoted immediately after I saw your and Sandy's answer, but as the site informs me "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score" :/

Comment: Oh, I missed the option of marking an answer as  accepted. I'm not only new to coding but also to this site, as you see. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are using your `ID` in "". So it is treated as `string`. 
You should use like:

`$("#" + expandingElement).show();`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct it's seem that you're looking for something similar to [Boostrap's Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Your failure was : 
**$("#expandingElement").show()/hide();**

Solution :
**$("#"+expandingElement).show()/hide();**

*expandingElement* is a variable, so if you insert it in btwn '' it becomes a string.

Anyway:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".concealed").hide();       

    $(".expander").click(function(){            
       $(".concealed").hide();
       var clickedElement = $(this).attr("id");   

       var expandingElement = "concealed-" + clickedElement;            

       $("#"+expandingElement).show();    

        });
    });
```